# Counting number of tilings of Aztec Diamond by $2 \times 1$ dominos respecting a fault line

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we split an Aztec Diamond into two regions, represented by the two shadings `.` and `o`.  What it the total number of tilings by $2 \times 1$ rectangles?

I have counted $\#(\cdot)=2$ and $\#(\circ)=6$ therefore, the number of tilings respecting the fault line is: $\# = 2 \times 6 = 12$ out of possible $2^{1+2+3} = 64$ tilings, so that $\sf{P} = \frac{3}{16}$.

```
  ..
 ....
...ooo
..oooo
 .ooo
  oo
```

If we use the formula in this paper, ([[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9906120)] page 30)  the formula reads:

$$ \sf{P}=\frac{ (3-0)^2 \times \binom{3}{0} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 \times 
\binom{3}{3} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 }{2! \times \frac{0!1!}{3!2!} \times (3!)^2 \times \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}  = \frac{3}{32}$$

```
     _ _
   _|   |_
 _|    _ _|_
|    _|     |
|_  |      _|
  |_|    _|
    |_ _|
```

Did I slip?  The theorem gives a probability but I turned it back into a number by diving by $2^6$.

Comment: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_diamond)

Comment: @JeanMarie without the fault line, the number of tilings is 64.  If we split the region in two, as I have drawn, the numbr of tilings is 12?  However, this other resource shows the number of tilings is only 6.  I'd believe my own counting.